# How to select data from table according to dates in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, date

I have a table called `tasks`. In the index file all the tasks are being listed. There is a column name `date` in `tasks`. The date is saved in  YYYY-MM-DD format. I want to get all the rows whose date is 2016-**numbers-from-0-to-12**-**numbers-from-0-to-30**.

example date is:

```
2016-12-1
```

Comment: post your attempts..

Comment: I dont know how to write regaular expressions in php

Comment: you need it in ascending order or descending order ?

Comment: @jilesh i want to get the data in descending order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply filter the records by specifying date range.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tasks
WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
ORDER BY date DESC
```

**Update**

To get records from current date:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tasks
WHERE date BETWEEN curdate() AND '2016-12-31'
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: Ok i will check it @samir

Comment: can i get the dates after before 2016-1-6